# Removing www from URL and using directory-like URL's

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an issue removing the `www` from an URL. Also I want to use directory-like URL's (e.g. When I type `www.foo.com/bar/baz` into URL bar, it is converted into `foo.com/index?page=bar&action=baz` in the background **and only in the background**). But what I'm getting is that when I type in the URL with `www` and hit an Enter, I get back a `foo.com/index?page=bar&action=baz` in the URL bar. I only want `foo.com/bar/baz` to appear. (If I already wrote the URL without `www`, it's working fine.)

This is my code (only changed the original URL's):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.foo\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://foo.com$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/index\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/Views/.*\.js
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/Views/.*\.css
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)(/[^/]+)* /index.php?page=$1&action=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/index\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/Views/.*\.js
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/Views/.*\.css
RewriteRule ^([^/]+) /index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

So my question is obviously: What am I doing wrong and how can I make it work?

Comment: Your first rule is marked with the `L` flag, which means "Last" - no more rules will be run if it matches... so you're just removing the `www.`.  Remove the `L` flags from your Rules.

Comment: That's not making any sense. My problem is even showing that the second rule is running.

Comment: Ah sorry, I misread what you were getting when you entered a URL.

Comment: cant see any external redirects to index.php in rules, so assume that there are cached redirects as browsers can do it.

Answer (score 0):

There may be some other Apache rules in play but from the look of it there may be an issue with slashes.  It would be better if your first rule was this --

```
RewriteRule (.*) http://foo$1 [L,R=301]
```

Without the trailing slash.  The reason for this is you will create a double // when redirecting www.foo.com/foo/bar.  It will redirect to foo.com//foo/bar.

Your other rules should start with /, e.g. --

```
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)(/[^/]+)* /index.php?page=$1&action=$2 [L,QSA]
```

And --

```
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+) /index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks, that was really an issue. Anyway, the result is the same. :-( I've edited my question.